# Why do my bash script is not prallelizing on server even if I use '&'?

Tags: bash, server, parallel-processing

Consider the following sample bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in 1 2 3 4; do
  for y in 1 2 3 4; do
      python name_$x.py --arg $y &
  done
done
```

When I run this script on my laptop, the program is executing on all the cores in my system. It is due to the usage of `&`.

But, when I try to run the same script on the server system, the program is exiting without any warning or error. If I remove `&` then my program is running sequentially, on a single node, on the server, which I don't want to do.

What can I do to execute all my 8 programs parallelly on 8 cores on the server?

Comment: shouldn't there be `16` programs running in parallel? what happens when you run a single invocation at the command line and put it in the background (eg, `python name_1.py --arg 1 &`) ... does it run? does it generate any output (what is the expected output/ressult of running the program)? are all software versions the same (`bash`, `python`, `name_*.py`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso The program is running well on all cores on my laptop. Each core is running a single instance.  But when I try the same thing on the server, it is exciting without any notification.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j8 --header : python name_{x}.py --arg {y} ::: x 1 2 3 4 ::: y 1 2 3 4
```

You can remove `-j8` if the server has 8 cores.